Windows and Ubuntu dual boot
I have a problem dual booting with Windows 11 and Ubuntu. I've installed Ubuntu, but when I switched to Windows, and come back to Ubuntu again, it tells me to download again. Like if you have download Ubuntu, it would show Ubuntu, safe graphic, windows boot manager and other stuff. When you haven't download Ubuntu yet, it would show "Try or install Ubuntu" but I've installed it and it's showing the same. Which means, my data that I saved after installing Ubuntu are lost. Why?

Apparently you forgot to remove the Ubuntu installation USB after installing Ubuntu. As a result the computer always boots to this Ubuntu installation USB instead of booting to the Ubuntu that you installed on your computer's hard drive.
Alternatively the computer would not automatically boot to a live USB if you changed the boot priority of the USB device in the BIOS to not be listed first in the BIOS's Boot priority menu. After the Ubuntu installation USB is no longer listed in first place in the BIOS boot priority menu the computer would boot to either Windows 11 or, if Ubuntu is installed successfully, to the GRUB boot menu.

Let me try that.
